# Javascript <span> button enable/disable on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a  button:

that by default is disabled and I enable/disable it programmatically

```
document.getElementById("moveBtn").disabled = true;
document.getElementById("moveBtn").disabled = false;
```

On IE11 works perfect but on Chrome when

```
document.getElementById("moveBtn").disabled = false;
```

is called the buttons are active (you can click on them) but still appear as disabled. Can I make it work also on Chrome like on IE?

```js
document.getElementById("moveBtn").disabled = true;
```

```css
//add some css code here
```

```html
 <button id="moveBtn" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalM" disabled><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Move"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></span></button>
```

Comment: *"I have a button"* No, you don't. You have a `span`. `span` elements have no `disabled` property, because they are not interactive elements.

Comment: Have you tried setting disable attribute using `setAttribute()`?

Comment: it's span not a button, it's don't have any disable prperty

Comment: IE implements disable attribute for the most of the elements, when other browsers don't. You have to emulate disabled state by adding suitable styling to `span`, and either create a flag the click handler detects, or detach the click event from the "button".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a button

No, you don't. You have a `span`. [`span` elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#htmlspanelement) have no `disabled` property, because they are not interactive elements:

```js
console.log("disabled" in document.createElement("span")); // false
```

Use an actual button (e.g., `<button type="button">...</button>`), which you can style as you like (looks like you're using Bootstrap, which already styles them for you):

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button type="button" id="moveBtn" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalM" disabled><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Move"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></span></button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I set it to button the tooltip would not appear on IE :(

Comment: @Dana: Then *that's* the problem to solve. You don't solve a tooltip problem by turning an interactive control into a non-interactive control. There's a fundamental difference between a `span` and a `button`.

Comment: Perhaps you are right. But I don't know what should I change :(

Comment: you were right! That was my actual problem :) I've added the tooltip to the button and the modal to the span and now it works! Whou could know? :) Thanks a lot for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

You should create a button... What you have is not a button, it is a span disguised in a button. But only buttons have the disabled property correctly working everywhere.

```
<button id="moveBtn" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalM" disabled><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Move"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></span></button>
```

Comment: If it's a <button> it won't work the tooltip, that's why I've made it a <span> with the button class

Comment: @Dana: Why can't you do the tooltip on a `button` element?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a `span` instead of `button` you can't expect it to react reliably to changes of random properties like `disabled`, `span` is not supposed to have this behaviour.

You can however achieve what you need by adding/removing `disabled` attribute if you really want to use `span`:

```
document.getElementById("moveBtn").removeAttribute('disabled')
```

But, you would better change your HTML to use button, in terms of styling it will not change anything, since Bootstrap defines `btn` styles agnostic from tag you use.

Answer (score 0):

span elements don't have **disabled property.**

Try this,

```
document.getElementById("moveBtn").style.pointerEvents = "none";//to disable span

document.getElementById("moveBtn").style.pointerEvents = "all";//to enable span
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can create a button to achieve whatever you are doing, or you can unbind click event on span or on clicking span, simply write return false;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<html>
<title></title>
<head>
   <style>
      btn.disable{"opacity": 0.6;"cursor": inherit;}
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="moveBtn" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalM" disabled><span data-toggle="tooltip" title="Move"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></span></span>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#moveBtn').click(function(){
             $(this).toggleClass('disable');
             // or else you can use toggle method
             $(this).toggle()
          });
       });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```